# Dynamically configuring spring state machine

Tags: spring-statemachine

Some queries on spring state machine.

1. Can we have more than one state machine  in a single spring project,
   where in one state machine serves for one work flow (may be a CD
   player work flow)  and the  other for a turnstile?
2. Can I dynamically load the configuration in my config class, for instance from a big data source having JSON formatted data, where we stores our states, events, transitions etc.
3. One of my requirement is I may be having a frequently changing worklow or model, which I needs to configured in my spring project. How can I effectively do that with spring state machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can have multiple machines. `@EnableStateMachine` has `id` property for a bean name. You can expose config as `@EnableStateMachineFactory`. If you want to work outside of javaconfig there is a manual builder model for it.

2/3) There is a public configuration api between javaconfig and statemachine. One user(outside of javaconfig) of this config model is uml based modeling which uses [eclipse's uml xml](http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#sm-papyrus) file to load the config. Uml is your best bet as we don't have other build-in configuration hooks at this moment. contributions welcome ;)

Comment: Thanks Janne! Can you give the github url for samples which makes use of a manual builder model

Comment: It's in docs http://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/1.1.0.RC1/reference/htmlsingle/#state-machine-via-builder and `eventservice` sample is using it https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-statemachine/blob/master/spring-statemachine-samples/eventservice/src/main/java/demo/eventservice/StateMachineConfig.java

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the State machine dynamically using Builder. Builder is using same configuration interfaces behind the scenes that the @Configuration model using adapter classes.
Example:

```
StateMachine<String, String> buildMachine1() throws Exception {
    Builder<String, String> builder = StateMachineBuilder.builder();
    builder.configureStates()
        .withStates()
            .initial("S1")
            .end("SF")
            .states(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList("S1","S2","S3","S4")));
    return builder.build();
}
```

Link to official docs: [Dynamic Spring State Machine](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-statemachine/1.2.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/sm-factories.html)